# Caching Pattern for Fetching Collections

Tags: c#, performance, caching, design-patterns, async-await

Is there a caching strategy/pattern that can be used for fetching multiple items, where only some may be cached?  Does it make sense to use a cache in such scenarios?

**More Detail**

Where the cache would return a single (or known number of) result(s) caching's simple; if it's in the cache we return it, if not we fetch it, add it to the cache, then return it:

```
//using System.Runtime.Caching;
ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
TimeSpan cacheLifetime = new TimeSpan(0, 20, 0);
SomeObjectFinder source = new SomeObjectFinder();
public SomeObject GetById(long id)
{
    return GetFromCacheById(id) ?? GetFromSourceById(id);
}
protected SomeObject GetFromCacheById(long id)
{
    return (SomeObject)cache.Get(id.ToString(),null);
}
protected SomeObject GetFromSourceById (long id)
{
    SomeObject result = source.GetById(id);
    return result == null ? null : (SomeObject)cache.AddOrGetExisting(id.ToString(), result, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(cacheLifetime), null);
}
```

However, where we don't know how many results to expect, if we fetched the results from the cache we wouldn't know that we'd fetched everything; only what's been cached.  So following the above pattern, if none of or all of the results had been cached we'd be fine; but if half of them had been, we'd get a partial result set.

I was thinking the below may make sense; but I've not played with `async`/`await` before, and most of what I've read implies that calling async code from synchronous code is generally considered bad; so this solution's probably not a good idea.

```
public IEnumerable<SomeObject> GetByPartialName(string startOfName)
{
    //kick off call to the DB (or whatever) to get the full result set 
    var getResultsTask = Task.Run<IList<SomeObject>>(async() => await GetFromSourceByPartialNameAsync(startOfName));
    //whilst we leave that to run in the background, start getting and returning the results from the cache
    var cacheResults = GetFromCacheByPartialName(startOfName);
    foreach (var result in cacheResults)
    {
        yield return result;
    }
    //once all cached values are returned, wait for the async task to complete, remove the results we'd already returned from cache, then add the remaining results to cache and return those also
    var results = getResultsTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    foreach (var result in results.Except(cacheResults))
    {
        yield return CacheAddOrGetExistingByName(result.Name, result);
    }
}
protected async Task<IList<SomeObject>> GetFromSourceByPartialNameAsync(string startOfName)
{
    return source.GetByPartialName(startOfName);
}
```

My assumption is that the answer's going to be "in this scenario either cache everything beforehand, or don't use cache"... but hopefully there's some better option.

Comment: If you have to go to the (relatively slow) source every time to check anyway, then perhaps that collection type is just not well-suited for caching?  I don't think async will help you much here - an async call is no faster than a sync one - actually marginally slower; you just get to do other stuff while you're waiting for it to complete.  So you would still end up needing to wait for a lot longer than it takes to fetch the cached items and return them, before you can return to the caller.

Comment: Thanks @sellotape; that fits with my assumption.  The benefit in the above would be that as we're returning `IEnumerable` any processing to be done after the results are fetched can start looping through the first (cached) values whilst the others are still being fetched; but I agree that any benefit of this is likely lost in the added complexity outside of extreme edge cases.

Comment: @JohnLBevan: just be aware that `IEnumerable` return values could result in multiple calls to the method, which in turn could result in a undesirable outcome at times (e.g.  collection values keep mutating). If you are not containing those behaviors, it might be best to return an `IList<T>` instead.  Regarding caching, I've found the `IDictionary<T1, T2>` to be highly performant, so long as it's all in-memory. If you need to persist, SQLite is _very fast_.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Decorator and strategy pattern, here is the link to [Steve Smith post regarding building a cached repository](https://ardalis.com/building-a-cachedrepository-via-strategy-pattern), and for individual items work as well, so you can use a decorator using redis and if not found it goes to the database and then save it to database, after that querying the data will be really fast.

Here is some sample code:

```
public class CachedAlbumRepository : IAlbumRepository
{
    private readonly IAlbumRepository _albumRepository;

public CachedAlbumRepository(IAlbumRepository albumRepository)
{
    _albumRepository = albumRepository;
}

private static readonly object CacheLockObject = new object();

public IEnumerable<Album> GetTopSellingAlbums(int count)
{
    Debug.Print("CachedAlbumRepository:GetTopSellingAlbums");
    string cacheKey = "TopSellingAlbums-" + count;
    var result = HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey] as List<Album>;
    if (result == null)
    {
        lock (CacheLockObject)
        {
            result = HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey] as List<Album>;
    if (result == null)
            {
                result = _albumRepository.GetTopSellingAlbums(count).ToList();
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, result, null, 
                    DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60), TimeSpan.Zero);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
}
```